# "Went to school happily" vs. "happily went to school" vs. "went happily to school"

Tags: adverbs, word-order, semantics

> 1. The boy went to school happily.
> 2. The boy happily went to school.
> 3. The boy went happily to school.

If the adverb “happily” is allowed to be put in the three places above, what are the different impressions you think it will give to readers?

Comment: This question was just asked. I assume you saw it? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142522/what-are-the-differences-between-go-to-school-happily-go-happily-to-school